# How to unit test ES6 modules with internal dependencies

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, es6-modules

Writing unit tests and ran into a complication when I have a function that includes a dependency on another function within the same module. This is the pattern:

```
export function foo(){
  ...do stuff...
}
export function bar(){
  const thing = foo();
  ...do stuff...
}
```

When I import these into my test file (using ES6 syntax), I don't seem to be able to stub foo() for testing bar(), because bar() always refers to the version of foo() in the module scope and not in my local testing scope. At least, I think that's the problem.

I managed to find other questions on this site about similar issues, but the solution seems to always be to rework the code in the module instead of some clever workaround in the test file. Is there no workaround for this, short of rewriting the code in the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation seems similar to this:

```
class X {
    foo() { return this.bar(); }
    bar{} { return true; }
}
```

And your question is: how do I test `foo` with a stub for `bar`. Like this you can't. If you want to be able to substitute an implementation of `bar` you need to rewrite how `foo` works.

To me it seems like `bar` does something that's useful on it's own and `foo` uses the result of `bar`. Then you can wonder if `foo` and `bar` should be in the same class/module. Maybe `bar` can be in a class/module on it's own.

Like:

```
class Bar {
    bar() { return true; }
}
class Foo {
    constructor(bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    foo() { return this.bar(); }
}
```

Now `foo` has a dependency on `bar` and you can substitute it's implementation.